# What protocol does MFMailComposer use to send mail?

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

What protocol apple has used to send mail through MFMailComposer?SMTP or other Protocol?
any help please?

Answer (score 2):

If uses your default mail settings. If you have set your default mail account as Microsoft Exchange, it will use that, and if it is SMTP (with our without SSL), that will be used.
Generally while using MFMailComposer, you don't need to worry about the protocol. If the default mail account is set properly, the mail can be sent.

Answer (score 1):

The mail composed using `MFMailComposer` is sent just as regular e-mail composed in the Mail application. In other words it’s SMTP.